# How to store_true and store value in a mutual exclusive group in argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I want to do something like this:

```
usage: myprogpy [-su | -re STRING | -reg]
```

How do I check which of the arguments were given (`su`, `re`, `reg`), and in the case of `re`, obtain the given string?

```py
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="myprog.py")
    method_group = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    method_group.add_argument('-su', '--speedup', action='store_true', dest='method')
    method_group.add_argument('-re', '--relative', action='store_true', dest='method')
    method_group.add_argument('-reg', '--regular', action='store_true', dest='method')
    args = ap.parse_args()

    if args.method == "speedup":
        speedup()

    elif args.method == "relative":
        relative(string_value) # How do I get the string value???

    elif args.method == "regular":
        regular()
```

Is it possible to get assign `true/false` value in `method`, as well as storing the string in a different variable? Is there another way?

Comment: What do you want `args.method` to be if *none* of the three options is given?

Comment: @chepner Um, probably just a default value

Comment: If you want to provide a string, why are you using `store_true` for `--re`?  You want the default `store`.  For now don't fiddle with the `dest` in `argparse`.  Test `args.su`, `args.re` and `args.reg` after.  That way you don't loose any information during parsing.

Comment: A group just keeps users from using more than one of those arguments,  They can still use their own default dest.  In fact using a common `dest` reduces the information you get.

Answer (score 0):

Use the (default) `'store'` and `'store_const'` actions, not `'store_true'`.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="myprog.py")
method_group = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
method_group.add_argument('-su', '--speedup',
                          action='store_const',
                          const='speedup',
                          dest='method')
method_group.add_argument('-re', '--relative',
                          dest='method')
method_group.add_argument('-reg', '--regular',
                          action='store_const',
                          const='regular',
                          dest='method')
args = ap.parse_args()

if args.method == "speedup":
    speedup()
elif args.method == "regular":
    regular()
elif args.method is not None:
    relative(args.method)
```

Comment: What if i wanted to do [-su | -re STRING | -reg STRING]. Then how should I know whether the string should be handled by `re` or `reg`?

Comment: You could define a custom action that would make note of both which option was used and what its argument is.

Comment: If you have to distinguish between `re` and `reg`, use the default `dest`.  Trying to assign all to the same `method` dest just makes life complicated.